# Tried to derive the Z combinator and instead derived another

Tags: lambda-calculus, combinatory-logic

I was working to derive the Z-Combinator by starting with the factorial function and ended up deriving a different fixed-point combinator. What did I derive? Did I make a subtle mistake?

Here are the steps I performed (in JavaScript)

### 1. Declare factorial function

```js
let fact = n =>
    n < 2 ? 1 : n * fact(n - 1)
```

### 2. Convert to combinator (closed expression)

```js
let fact = (self, n) =>
    n < 2 ? 1 : n * self(n - 1)
```

### 3. Thread self call

Based on signature `fact(?, 7)`, passing `fact` as first argument seems reasonable `fact(fact,7)`. So thread the parameter through the tail call:

```js
let fact = (self, n) =>
    n < 2 ? 1 : n * self(self, n - 1)
```

Usage is now `fact(fact,7)` → `5040`

### 4. Refactor to curried form

```js
let fact = self =>
    n => n < 2 ? 1 : n * self(self)(n - 1)
```

### 5. Move self application to local declaration

```js
let fact = self => {
    let f = n => self(self)(n)
    return n => n < 2 ? 1 : n * f(n - 1)
}
```

### 6. Convert let declaration to lambda expression

```js
let fact = self =>
    (f =>
        n => n < 2 ? 1 : n * f(n - 1)
    )(
        n => self(self)(n)
    )
```

Usage is still `fact(fact)(7)` → `5040`

### 7. Separate the factorial expression

```js
let _fact = f => n =>
    n < 2 ? 1 : n * f(n - 1)

let fact = self =>
    (
        _fact
    )(
        n => self(self)(n)
    )
```

### 8. Move self-application from caller to body

```js
let _fact =
    f => n => n < 2 ? 1 : n * f(n - 1)

let fact = (() => {
    let innerFact = self =>
        (
            _fact
        )(
            n => self(self)(n)
        )
    return innerFact(innerFact)
})()
```

Usage is now `fact(7)` → `5040`

### 9. Convert let declaration to lambda expression

```js
let _fact =
    f => n => n < 2 ? 1 : n * f(n - 1)

let fact = (() => {
    return (
        innerFact => innerFact(innerFact)
    )(
        self => (_fact)(n => self(self)(n))
    )
})()
```

### 10. Simplify expression

```js
let _fact =
    f => n => n < 2 ? 1 : n * f(n - 1)

let fact =
    (innerFact => innerFact(innerFact))
    (self => (_fact)(n => self(self)(n)))
```

Sanity check. Usage is still `fact(7)` → `5040`

### 11. Rename variables

The usage of `innerFact` and `self` look suspiciously similar. Rename to the same variable to discover a pattern. Separate lexical scopes so safe to do:

```js
let _fact =
    f => n => n < 2 ? 1 : n * f(n - 1)

let fact =
    (u => u(u))
    (u => (_fact)(n => u(u)(n)))
```

### 12. Abstract `_fact` usage and rename `fact`

Rename `fact` to `setup` and abstract `_fact` in body by replacing with parameter `f`

```js
let _fact =
    f => n => n < 2 ? 1 : n * f(n - 1)

let setup = f =>
    (u => u(u))
    (u => (f)(n => u(u)(n)))

let fact = setup(_fact)
```

No need for separate `_fact` declaration so inline:

```js
let setup = f =>
    (u => u(u))
    (u => (f)(n => u(u)(n)))

let fact = setup(
    f => n => n < 2 ? 1 : n * f(n - 1)
)
```

### 13. Rename `setup`

Rename it to what? What combinator is this? According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Fixed-point_combinators_in_lambda_calculus) The Z combinator is:

```js
let Z = f => 
    (u => f(v => u(u)(v)))
    (u => f(v => u(u)(v)))
```

But what I've derived is:

```js
let setup = f =>
    (u => u(u))
    (u => (f)(n => u(u)(n)))
```

Defining `fact` in terms of either seems equivalent in behavior. Did I make a mistake? Did I accidentally rediscover another well-known combinator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I inline `(u => (f)(n => u(u)(n)))` into `(u => u(u))` I get:

```js
(u => f(n => u(u)(n)))
(u => f(n => u(u)(n)))
```

Which is exactly the Z-Combinator.

From wikipedia:

```js
let Z = f => 
    (u => f(v => u(u)(v)))
    (u => f(v => u(u)(v)))
```

My derivation:

```js
let fix = f =>
    (u => f(n => u(u)(n)))
    (u => f(n => u(u)(n)))
```